# Slice dictionary based on Numpy array values

Tags: python, numpy

I have one matrix called **m_hat** of shape k x 2, while k is an arbitrary number.

```
17.574  17.8316
22.449  23.0995
13.4923 11.8801
8.34949 8.0102
16.676  17.2908
24.8699 25.2985
13.7985 12.8801
13.4541 13.9107
14.7577 14.9133
47.0102 48.4668
```

I want to make a scatter plot with x axis being the first column of **m_hat** and y axis being the second column of **m_hat**. This can be done with this line code.

```
plt.scatter(m_hat[:, 0], m_hat[:, 1])
```

Now I want to put colors on the data based on labels. So, I have a dictionary containing the label and the respective colors.

```
cdict = {1: 'red', 3: 'green', 5: 'blue', 7: 'yellow'}
```

And the lines to code the scatter plot along with colors are these, YET this is an extremely slow process:

```
[plt.scatter(m_hat[:, 0], m_hat[:, 1], c=cdict[cl]) for cl in l_train]
```

With `l_train` being an array with the respective labels.

```
1
1
1
1
1
1
1
1
1
1
```

I have tried to do something like sclicing the dictionary based on **l_train**:

```
[plt.scatter(m_hat[:, 0], m_hat[:, 1], c=cdict[l_train])]
```

Yet this error occurs:

```
TypeError: unhashable type: 'numpy.ndarray'
```

How can I do my job AND avoiding any kind of for loop, that is only with numpy sclicing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The dict-indexing is not vectorizable with numpy arrays, this is where you have to have an iteration. But you an use a list comprehension for this so you only have one call to `plt.scatter` which will be a lot faster, so just replace

```
[plt.scatter(m_hat[:, 0], m_hat[:, 1], c=cdict[cl]) for cl in l_train]
```

with

```
plt.scatter(m_hat[:, 0], m_hat[:, 1], c=[cdict[cl] for cl in l_train])
```

Comment: Saved me some valuable time. Thanks.